# CDK/Cloudformation shared state

Tags: terraform, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, terraform-remote-state

Pretty new to CDK/Cloudformation, just moving from Terraform, and was wondering if CDK/Cloudformation have something similar to Terraform's remote state? Or some other way that different team members could work on updating the same AWS resources without need to destroy/recreate everything.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why CDK does not have a state file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CDK is just a "wrapper" around CloudFormation, which means that AWS stores the state and manages your resources deployed using CDK.

Terraform does not use CloudFormation, thus it has to keep its own state. Also Terraform is cloud agnostic, so it manages state without needing to rely on any cloud resources, such as CloudFormation.

So no, CDK does not have its own state in the same sense as Terraform has.

Comment: There are AWS SDK with CloudFormationClients that can help retrieve the state from CloudFormation.  Don't know what languages you use but there are AWS SDK for Java, Go, .net, etc.

Comment: Ideally SDK shouldn't be involved at this point. We're dealing with infrastructure, not actual application code.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter As I explained TF is not CDK nor CloudFormation. It does not have any state file outside of AWS.

Comment: Yes I understand that. So I am still looking for the ability for different people from different locations to work on the same infrastructure.